# Which method is faster for Python iterating?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating a new list from a large old list based on a certain value being not equal to None. Which method of iteration is faster?

Option 1:

```
new_list = []
for values in old_list:
   if values[4] is not None:
       new_list.append(values[4])
```

Option 2:

```
new_list = [x for x in old_list if x[4] is not None]
```

Comment: You could test this for yourself using the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module.

Comment: I have a request. Please don't put a space between `new_list` and `.append`. I couldn't find anything in the Python style guide specifically forbidding it, so just consider it a personal favor to me ;-)

Comment: @Kevin - favor granted!

Comment: Option 2 is faster - I tested this sort of thing 5 years ago on python2.7. Back then, it was about 10x faster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to `timeit` both.

But second is widely [known to be faster](http://blog.cdleary.com/2010/04/efficiency-of-list-comprehensions/).

Basically `map` is faster than `list comprehension` which is faster than `for loop`.

A **whole lot** of literature is available on the web about this subject.

**EDIT:**

I **promised** an update with actual, tangible results. Here is the code.

```
import random
import timeit

old_list = [ random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(0, 100) ]


def floop(old_list):
    new_list = []
    for value in old_list:
        new_list.append(value)
    return new_list


def lcomp(old_list):
    new_list = [ value for value in old_list ]
    return new_list


if __name__=='__main__':
    results_floop = timeit.Timer('floop(old_list)', "from __main__ import floop, old_list").timeit()
    results_lcomp = timeit.Timer('lcomp(old_list)', "from __main__ import lcomp, old_list").timeit()
    print("Function\t\tSeconds elapsed")
    print("For loop\t\t{}".format(results_floop))
    print("List comp\t\t{}".format(results_lcomp))
```

Remember: `timeit` loops through the called function 1 million times and prints the time elapsed in seconds. Read it like *to execute this 1 million times, it took xx seconds*.

Here are the results. I think they speak by themselves.

```
~/python » python3 lists.py
Function        Seconds elapsed
For loop        11.089475459069945
List comp       5.985794545034878
```

Comment: You might want to put in some timeit results of your own, in case the link ever rots.

Comment: @Ffisegydd you're right - will be updating this answer soon with some results

Comment: Cool, I did not know about timeit. I chose this as a best answer, but would still like to see the example.

Answer (score 1):

The second is both faster, and more readable. If you need more speed, and are only iterating through the result once, you could use `filter` - `new_list = filter(lambda x: x[4] is not None, old_list)`. You could call `list` on the filtered result, but that might not have any speed advantage over the list comprehension (and is less Pythonic IMHO).